# How to make an Android app fetching live data(order books, market depths) from cryptocurrency exchanges?

Tags: api, android-studio, websocket, bitcoin

I decided to start with only one exchange(preferably Bitfinex) by displaying its real time order book.
I have taken some Android development courses but I am not sure on how to start. I know that we fetch data by using exchanges'APIs and websocket. Can someone give me some advice on how to build that into my app? Any other advice on how to start would be appreciated too.

Answer (score -1):

I recently developed an Android App which converts Bitcoin To Different Units like (USD/INR/.. 20 more) using coindesk free API.
Please refer this https://www.coindesk.com/api/

Comment: Link to my app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=crypto.trackbitcoin.bitcointrack&hl=en

Comment: It seems this app doesn't have live order books and market depths :(